# How can I create a series of numbers increasing by a decimal in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a series of numbers for multiple samples using a distribution plot. I want to have numbers .01, .02, .03... etc. in a column by itself, just creating a random number.

I have tried randbetween(0,1) but I cannot have it run a specified number of times and it is also not in sequence. I also tried rand() but that didn't work either.

The output should be something like this:

1. 0.000001
2. 0.000002
3. 0.000003
4. 0.000004
   ..... etc

Comment: Do you want a sequence of random numbers? or a sequence of ordered numbers in a range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `generate_array()` to generate a series of numbers.  Then divide:

```
select cast(n / 1000000 as numeric)
from unnest(generate_array(1, 10)) n
```